# How prove this inequality $f(x)\le\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}(x-1)\le\frac{3}{2}(x-1),x>0$

Tags: inequality

> let $a,b,c,d$ be positive numbers,and such
>   $$(1):\dfrac{a+b}{c+d}=\dfrac{3}{2}$$
>   $$(2):2a\ge c, 2a\le 3b,2d\ge c,2a\le 3c$$
>   let function:$f(x)=\ln{x}+\sqrt{x}-1$.
>
> show that
>   $$f(x)\le\dfrac{ax+b}{cx+d}(x-1)\le\dfrac{3}{2}(x-1),x>0$$

My try:
let $$c=2a-u,3b=2a+v,u,v\ge0$$
since
$$2(a+b)=3(c+d)\Longrightarrow d=u-\dfrac{8}{9}a+\dfrac{2v}{9}$$
since
$$2d\ge c\Longrightarrow 27u+4v\ge 34a$$
since
$$2a\le 3c\Longrightarrow u\le\dfrac{4}{3}a$$

then 
$$\Longleftrightarrow \ln{x}+\sqrt{x}-1\le\dfrac{ax+\dfrac{2a}{3}+\dfrac{v}{3}}{(2a-u)x+x-\dfrac{8}{9}a+\dfrac{2v}{9}}(x-1)\le\dfrac{3}{2}(x-1)$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow \ln{x}+\sqrt{x}-1\le\dfrac{9ax+6a+3v}{9(2a-u+1)x-8a+2v}(x-1)\le\dfrac{3}{2}(x-1)$$
where $$u\le\dfrac{4}{3}a,27u+4v\ge 34a,x>0,u>0,v>0$$

**By right hand**:

> $$\Longleftrightarrow  \dfrac{9ax+6a+3v}{9(2a-u+1)x-8a+2v}(x-1)\le\dfrac{3}{2}(x-1)$$
>   if $x\ge 1$
>   $$\Longleftrightarrow \dfrac{9ax+6a+3v}{9(2a-u+1)x-8a+2v}\le\dfrac{3}{2}$$
>   $$\Longleftrightarrow -27ux+27x-36a+36ax\ge 0$$
>   so let $$g(u)=-27ux+27x-36a+36ax,0\le u\le\dfrac{4}{3}a$$
>   so we $$g(\dfrac{4}{3}a)=27x-36a$$
>   **But this is not alway is true? my methods is wrong? Thank you**

Comment: Can you check condition (2)? It seems to me the last inequality should by something else, based on the symmetry?

Comment: Yeah, please check the conditions. Take $a=d=1/2$, $c=1$, $b=7/4$. Mathematica evaluates $f(x)$ to be *larger* than $(ax+b)/(cx+d)$ at $x=0.99$.

Comment: Oh,Thank you,maybe this inequality is not true

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the question. If one takes $a=d=\frac{1}{2}$, $c=1$, and $b=\frac{7}{4}$, the inequality $f(x)\le \frac{a x + b}{c x + d}$ does *not* hold. Take, for example, $x=0.99$.

I will prove the other inequality, i.e.,
$$
\frac{a x + b}{c x +d} (x-1) \le \frac{3}{2}(x-1).
$$
I'll also give a sufficient condition on $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ to ensure the first inequality does, in fact, hold.

Define
$$
g(x) = \frac{a x + b}{c x +d} (x-1).
$$
Recall
$$
f(x) = \ln x + \sqrt{x} - 1.
$$
Also, define
$$
h(x) = \frac{3}{2}(x-1).
$$
We wish to show $f(x)\le g(x) \le h(x)$ for all $x>0$.

Scaling $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ by any positive constant does not alter $g(x)$ nor any of the given constraints. Thus, without loss of generality, we may assume $c=1$. The constraints then become a little easier to understand:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{a+b}{1 + d} &=& \frac{3}{2} \\
\frac{1}{2} &\le& a \le \frac{3}{2} \\
a &\le& \frac{3}{2} b\\
\frac{1}{2} &\le& d.
\end{eqnarray}

First, note
$$
a + b = \frac{3}{2} (d + 1),
$$
so
\begin{eqnarray}
ad - b &=& ad - \left(\frac{3}{2} (d + 1) - a\right) \\
 &=& (d+1)\left(a-\frac{3}{2} \right) \\
 &\le& 0.
\end{eqnarray}

Next, observe some facts about $g$ and $h$:
\begin{eqnarray}
g(1) &=& h(1) = 0 \\
g'(1) &=& h'(1) = \frac{3}{2} \\
g''(x) &=& \frac{2(1+d) (a d - b)}{(x+d)^3} \le 0 \\
g''(x) &\le& h''(x) = 0 \mbox{ for all } x > 0.
\end{eqnarray}
This shows $g(x) \le h(x)$ for all $x>0$.

Now consider $f$, which is just a bit tougher. Just as with $h$, note
\begin{eqnarray}
g(1) &=& f(1) = 0 \\
g'(1) &=& f'(1) = \frac{3}{2}.
\end{eqnarray}
Also,
$$
f''(x) = -\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{4}x^{-\frac{3}{2}} = -\frac{\sqrt{x} + 4}{4x^2}.
$$
Now is it true that $f''(x)\le g''(x)$? If so, we will have proved the result. As noted above, the given constraints are not sufficient to prove this. But if, for example, in addition to the given constraints, we have
$$
3 d \ge (3-2a)(d+1)^2,
$$
then $f''(x)\le g''(x)\le 0$, and we will have $f(x)\le g(x)$.